# Some issues in logs after the upgrade to 20.04

Tags: boot, upgrade, login, gdm

I am a newbie in ubuntu, and would be most grateful if you could help me in an appropriate manner, please, if you can.
I have upgraded the 18.04 system to the 20.04 version on my v3-471G acer aspire laptop with some problems on the way, i.e. in the beginning it booted into a black screen, which I managed to fix by editing the /etc/default/grub file, and thought the problems went away, but that was a wrong guess.
For starters, the system loads for too long, but may be it isn't much of a problem. Then on the login screen it sometimes stops in such a manner that it allows me to enter a password but not to enter any further - the screen just blacks out and then the login screen with a blank password field reappears, I enter the password again and again and everything repeats indefinitely, until I manually reboot the machine. This happens not on every boot - only sometimes. At other times I just log into the system well.
In the "important" tab of the logs on every boot there are some issues which I haven't been able to solve yet. Hope you can say something on these: 
 1.
 Type - "other"
 Sender - gdm-session-wor
Message - gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file
Priority - 3
2.
Type - Hardware
 Message - sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
 Kernel Device - +scsi:6:0:0:0
Priority - 3
3.
Type - Hardware
 Message - sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
 Kernel Device - +scsi:6:0:0:0
Priority - 3
 Here are the screenshots of these three, if you'd like:
1. [gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAADb.png),
2. [[sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azRv5.png)
 3. [[sdc] No Caching mode page found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U27P.png).

What I've tried: 
switch from gdm3 to lightdm;
reinstalling gdm3;
installing proprietary nvidia driver;
switching on and off the Wayland login screen;
installing ubuntu gnome desktop.
 
These were all advises for various close issues I managed to find, but none of them worked for me - the issues do not disappear from the logs.

What can I do to fix it? Most of all I do not want to reinstall ubuntu...

Comment: Don't screenshot logs, either paste them here with appropriate formatting or pastebin them, images are woefully inappropriate for text. Given you have 8 lines of logs, pasting them would have made a clearer and more complete question.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Edited and pasted the logs in the text.